# How i can convert to double .dart

Tags: dart, operators, dart-io

I have problem in this code, this code can not be executed. Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print("CALCULATOR");

  stdout.write("Number a: ");
  double a = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  stdout.write("Number b: ");
  double b = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  double result;

  // operator +
  result = a + b;
  print("$a + $b = $result");

  // operator -
  result = a - b;
  print("$a - $b = $result");

  // operator *
  result = a * b;
  print("$a * $b = $hasil");

  // operator /
  result = a / b;
  print("$a / $b = $result");

  // operator %
  result = a % b;
  print("$a % $b = $result");

}
```

This my problem:

```
myLearning/myNote/test.dart:7:33: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
double a = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
                            ^
myLearning/myNote/test.dart:9:33: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
double b = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

I just want if I input a number the result will be like this:

```
CALCULATOR
Number a : 9
Number b : 2
9.0 + 2.0 = 11.0
9.0 - 2.0 = 7.0
9.0 * 2.0 = 18.0
9.0 / 2.0 = 4.5
9.0 % 2.0 = 1.0
```

can I get input like the one above?

Comment: What error do you get? I can see a problem where you are using `hasil` which is not defined but the program runs fine if you replace `hasil` with `result`. Also, you example are properly not correct since 9 + 2 should not be 10 but 11.

Comment: @julemand101 sorry I typed the question wrong, I have edited it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "problem" is that you are using a beta version of Dart 2.12 which enables the non-nullable feature. This feature will help you ensure you are aware of all situations where a null value can happen. In your case it is the call to `stdin.readLineSync()`:

> Returns null if no bytes preceded the end of input.

You are getting an error because `double.parse` takes a `String` as argument but `stdin.readLineSync()` are returning `String?` which are a type which can be a `String` or `null` (where `String` only allows `String` and can never be `null`).

The easy fix is to do the following and inserting `!` after `readLineSync()`:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("CALCULATOR");

  stdout.write("Number a: ");
  double a = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  stdout.write("Number b: ");
  double b = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

  double result;

  // operator +
  result = a + b;
  print("$a + $b = $result");

  // operator -
  result = a - b;
  print("$a - $b = $result");

  // operator *
  result = a * b;
  print("$a * $b = $result");

  // operator /
  result = a / b;
  print("$a / $b = $result");

  // operator %
  result = a % b;
  print("$a % $b = $result");
}
```

By doing `!` you are telling Dart that you are sure the value is not null and the analyzer should just accept the value as if it is never `null`.

On runtime, Dart will add a runtime check for `null` and crash the program (with a NullPointerException) if the returned value from `stdin.readLineSync()` is `null`. But since we are working on a small example program, this is properly fine.

You can read more about non-null by default (NNBD) here: https://dart.dev/null-safety